# Dagger2 error: Kotlin: Unresolved reference: DaggerSOMETHINGComponent

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, kotlin, dagger-2

## source code

I'm building a gradle project of Kotlin and Dagger2 which runs well half year ago in macOS:

[GitHub:Kotlin-Tutorials13](https://github.com/enbandari/Kotlin-Tutorials/tree/master/code/Kt13)

you can get it by

```
git clone https://github.com/enbandari/Kotlin-Tutorials.git
cd Kotlin-Tutorials/code/Kt13
```

you can open it in IntelliJ IDEA

## building enviroment

My building enviroment is listed as below:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3
- JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 amd64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Windows 10 10.0

## building result

It tuens out an error:

```
C:\Users\xiang\IdeaProjects\Kotlin-Tutorials-master\code\Kt13\src\main\kotlin\net\println\kt13\Service.kt
Error:(3, 25) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: DaggerRESTFulComponent
Error:(19, 9) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: DaggerRESTFulComponent
```

## decompile

So, I decompile `RESTFulComponent.class`

the source file of it is `RESTFulComponent.kt`

```
package net.println.kt13

import dagger.Component
import net.println.kt13.module.RetrofitModule
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import javax.inject.Singleton

/**
 * Created by benny on 12/11/16.
 */
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(RetrofitModule::class))
interface RESTFulComponent {
    fun retrofit(): Retrofit
}
```

decompile `RESTFulComponent.class` we get

```
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available

package net.println.kt13.module

@dagger.Module public final class RxAdapterModule public constructor() {
    @javax.inject.Singleton @dagger.Provides public final fun adapter(): retrofit2.CallAdapter.Factory { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

## reason

The error result from *annotation of dagger*'s not working.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Usually there's more output by the Dagger compiler, which can help locate the problem. By the way, are you using kapt for annotation processing?

Comment: @Egor yes,I'm using kapt. you can see gradle config [here](https://github.com/enbandari/Kotlin-Tutorials/blob/master/code/Kt13/build.gradle#L38) . Unfortunately, there isn't more error output.

Comment: I actually ran into this problem and it was because ButterKnife doesn't handle nullable type for view properly and had to replace it with `lateinit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## wrong operation

I use **Ctrl+F9** to compile and this error arises。

## right operation

We should click **View** -> **Tool Windows** -> **Gradle** to open *Gradle projects* Window

Then click **Tasks** -> **build** -> **build**

[image: right build]

## reason

**Ctrl+F9** isn't invoking `gradle build`, we should use `gradle build` in *Gradle projects* Window

Comment: Thanks! I got the same issue in IntelliJ though it's not an android project. I just need to run a gradle build not to rebuild the whole project.